# How to populate array with results from a series of async requests

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, promise, xmlhttprequest

So I'm trying to get the names and scores that are in 2 arrays player_name and player_mmr. Calling both with player_name[i] and player_mmr[i] in the fillplayer function just returns undefined. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here but for the life of me can't figure it out. I'm guessing it has to do with the use of push.

```
var btnmatch = document.querySelector('#get-data');
var btnchat = document.querySelector('#get-chat');
var matchid = document.querySelector('#match-id');
var tableheaders = [
    'Hero',
    'level',
    'Name',
    'Kills',
    'Deaths',
    'assists',
    'GPM',
    'XPM',
    'HD',
    'TD'
];

var dataheaders = [
    "hero_id",
    'level',
    'personaname',
    'kills',
    'deaths',
    'assists',
    'gold_per_min',
    'xp_per_min',
    'hero_damage',
    'tower_damage'
];

var playerids = [
    'player1',
    'player2',
    'player3',
    'player4',
    'player5',
    'player6',
    'player7',
    'player8',
    'player9',
    'player10'
];

var playeraccounts = [];
var requests = [];
var playersdata = [];
var player_name = [];
var player_mmr = [];

btnmatch.addEventListener('click', function () {
    GetMatchData(matchid.value);

});

btnchat.addEventListener('click', function () {
    for (i in playeraccounts) {
        requests[i] = new GetPlayerData(playeraccounts[i]);
    }
    console.log(player_name);
    console.log(typeof player_name);
    console.log(player_mmr);
    fillplayer();

});


function GetPlayerData(accountid) {
    var Url = 'https://api.opendota.com/api/players/' + accountid;
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", Url, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function ProcessRequestPlayer() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            if (xmlHttp.responseText == "Not found") {
                console.log("not found");
            } else {
                var info = xmlHttp.responseText;
                var playerjson = JSON.parse(info);

                player_name.push(playerjson.profile.personaname);
                if (playerjson.solo_competitive_rank === null) {
                    player_mmr.push(playerjson.mmr_estimate.estimate);
                } else {
                    player_mmr.push(playerjson.solo_competitive_rank);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    xmlHttp.send();
}

function GetMatchData(id) {
    var Url = 'https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/' + id;
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", Url, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function ProcessRequestMatch() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            if (xmlHttp.responseText == "Not found") {
                console.log("not found")
            } else {
                var info = xmlHttp.responseText;
                var testjson = JSON.parse(info);

                createTable2(testjson);
                getaccountids(testjson);

            }
        }
    };
    xmlHttp.send();
}

function getaccountids(json) {
    Object.keys(json.players).forEach(function (i) {
        playeraccounts.push(json.players[i].account_id);
    });
}

function fillplayer() {
    console.log(player_name);
    console.log(player_mmr);
    for (var i = 0; i < playerids.length; i++) {
        console.log(player_name[i]);

        document.getElementById(playerids[i]).getElementsByClassName('name')[0].innerHTML = player_name + ': ';
        document.getElementById(playerids[i]).getElementsByClassName('mmr')[0].innerHTML = player_mmr[i];
    }
}

function createTable2(json) {
    // Create table.

    var table = "<table class='game-table'>";
    table += "<thead>";
    table += "<tr>";
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        table += "<th>" + tableheaders[i] + "</th>";

    }
    table += "</tr>";
    table += "</thead>";
    table += "<tbody>";

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        table += "<tr class='radiant'>";
        for (var x = 0; x < dataheaders.length; x++) {
            table += "<td>" + json.players[i][dataheaders[x]] + "</td>";
        }
        table += "</tr>";
    }

    for (var i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
        table += "<tr class='dire'>";
        for (var x = 0; x < dataheaders.length; x++) {
            table += "<td>" + json.players[i][dataheaders[x]] + "</td>";
        }
        table += "</tr>";
    }
    table += "</tbody>";
    table += "</table>";
    var sectie = document.getElementById('table');
    if (json.radiant_win == false) {
        var winnertekst = document.createTextNode('Dire Victory');
    } else {
        var winnertekst = document.createTextNode('Radiant Victory');
    }

    console.log(table);
    console.log(typeof table);
    console.log(sectie);
    document.getElementsByClassName('winnersect')[0].appendChild(winnertekst);
    sectie.innerHTML = table;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `player_name` and `player_nmr` are populated in the _callbacks_ of async requests and none or not all requests sent from `GetPlayerData` will have finished by time `fillplayer` is called. It is not predictable when and in what order the async requests will finish. You need to make sure `fillplayer` is called after the _last_ callback is finished. Use Promise.

Answer (score 0):

As marekful said you could use promises or you could take a look to [Async Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
and if you're not targeting IE as a browser, you could use the
[Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)
instead of XMLHttpRequest and have a cleaner structure. Both of these two return a promise that you can consume.
One more source that's showing how you can combine fetch and async functions
[JavaScript Fetch API and using Async/Await](https://dev.to/shoupn/javascript-fetch-api-and-using-asyncawait-47mp) .